# iOS 14 TextInput jumping and auto-scrolling on tap (React Native) - how to disable?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, ios14

New RN build from scratch. Only the code below exists.

Xcode version 12.0.1
iOS 14
RN 0.63.3

Scrolling and tapping makes TextInput jump to random places.

```
export default class TextField extends Component {

   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state={textInput: ''}
   }

  handleChangeText = (textInput) => {
    this.setState({ textInput });
  }

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
           <TextInput 
            style={{marginTop: 100, height: 300, backgroundColor: 'white'}}
            value={this.state.textInput}
            multiline={true}
            onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
          ></TextInput>     
        </View>
    )
}
```

Please view gif for example:
https://gph.is/g/ZdXD55W

How can this be disabled? Or fixed so that the autoscroll goes to the correct place?

Comment: No one? Also why was this downvoted?

Comment: I might be having the same issue with the  UIScrollView and UITextFields in native Swift code. There is a good chance that you won't be able to fix this within React Native.